# How to compress image size without effecting image quality?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to compress image size without effecting image quality? how can i create a function that take a image permater of a imageuri and then compress that image? I am using react native cli with Nodejs

How can i get this size

image: {
width: '130%',
aspectRatio: 1,
height: 600,
}

Comment: First off, it is [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) to compress the image without affecting image quality. Second, it is most certainly not the kind of job normally done by react (therefore, those tags are irrelevant).

Comment: @YevhenHorbunkov Please check my answer its possible

Comment: No, it isn't. The quality of your output image is 20% worse than that of your source image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well It's possible to compress the image without affecting image quality I found this package name react-native-image-resizer that I used to do that now my 3MB image is now 50kb only

```
const compressedImage = await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
    ImageUrl,
    600,
    600,
    'JPEG',
    80
);
```

Comment: The last parameter you pass to `createResizeImage()` is literally called **quality** and as the name suggests it indicates the quality loss compared to the original, so, essentially, your output image will have 20% worse quality than that of your source.

Comment: Let alone the fact this package is deprecated so using it in your project is not a smart choice, whatsoever.

Comment: @YevhenHorbunkov Its not deprecated but react-native-image-resizer has moved to @bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm module `sharp`. Try this code.

```
const sharp = require('sharp');

sharp(imageuri)
  .resize({
    width: 600,
    height: 600
  })
  .png({quality: 100})
  .toFile(outputuri, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Besides this, inside `resize` method you can use more parameters such as `fit`, `position`, `background` etc.
Please take a look at this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-process-images-in-node-js-with-sharp

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using react native I would suggest to use [react-native-compressor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor)

Then in the code you can do

```
import { Image as imageCompressor } from 'react-native-compressor';

const compressed = await imageCompressor.compress(uri, {
    compressionMethod: 'auto',
    returnableOutputType: 'uri',
})
```

Where `uri` is the path to your image. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13TsnC1c7NOC9aCjzN6wkKurJQPeGRNwDhWsQOkXQskU/edit#gid=0) are some examples of how the auto compression method works. You can also do manual compressions and can check the NPM package documentation for more info.